# SQLAlchemy: How to query an optional column on a self referential adjacency list table?

Tags: sqlalchemy, cascading, self-referencing-table

I have the following `Table` model representing a timeline.

```
class TimeRange(Base):


    __tablename__ = "time_line"


    record_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    level = Column(String, nullable=False) # e.g. "Point", "Range"
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    language_marker = Column(String) # this one column is optional and needs to be queried
    immediate_parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('time_line.record_id'))
    child_timelines = relationship('TimeRange', backref=backref('parent_timeline', remote_side=[record_id]))
```

The `language_marker` Column is the one that needs to be queried in a recursive manner. Not all records have such an attribute, and the business logic is: along the hierarchy lineage from the root down to the child timelines, at least one level of the `TimeRange` instance carries such an attribute, and the one in the lowest level should be returned. This works a little like cascading style sheet, where if the `TimeRange` object itself doesn't have such an attribute, just look further up one level above, util found one, and the latest defined style wins.

What is the technical direction I should look into to implement such queries? I'm using SQLAlchemy and the backend is SQLite. Thanks.

Comment: Is it ok performance-wise to do a select query for the parent `TimeRange` whenever `language_marker` is `None`?

Comment: @xli, thanks for your reply. It's absolutely ok. Now I'm clueless about the technical direction here. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a property `derived_language_marker` that starts with the current object and goes up the hierarchy of parent `TimeRange`s until it finds a language_marker that is not `None` and returns it:

```
 @property
 def derived_language_marker(self):
     time_range = self
     while not time_range.language_marker and time_range.parent_timeline:
         time_range = time_range.parent_timeline
     return time_range.language_marker
```

It can be accessed just as `time_range.derived_language_marker`, but the drawback is that it could result in a new `SELECT` query for each level it checks if the parent objects are not already loaded.

(If you are doing this for many `TimeRange`s and performance becomes a problem you can eager-load ancestors up to a certain depth with joins as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html#configuring-self-referential-eager-loading) as the long as the maximum possible depth is not too extreme. For further optimization, there is also [this approach](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/querying-tree-structures-in-sqlite-using-python-and-the-transitive-closure-extension/) for SQLite.)

Comment: one more plus for the conciseness and usefulness. I wish I could add one more the elegance.

Comment: could you give a little more explanation why using property and not hybrid_property, or even plain attributes directly on TimeRange? Thanks.

Comment: `hybrid_property` would allow you to make a query on `derived_language_marker` (like `filter(derived_language_marker == some_value)`), but it would need to be possible to convert the logic into a SQL expression, which isn't possible as it currently is. If you need functionality like that, you could try looking at the second link. With a plain attribute, you would need to create the column in the table, but then you would need to keep that column continually updated.